# Why does Entity Framework throw "String or binary data would be truncated" exception?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

If you take a look at the code below, you'll see that I'm attempting to add the same data to my context in two different ways. One--Method A, which I typically use with no problems--keeps throwing this exception when I call SaveChanges() on my context:

> An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. INNER EXCEPTION: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

I know the data isn't too long for the database field because Method B, which uses exactly the same data as Method A but which is for obvious reasons not the ideal way to insert, works fine. The only difference between them is that in Method B, I'm creating a new instance of my entity class in the method that talks to the DbContext and assigning to its properties the property values of the entity instance passed into that method. Can anyone explain what might be happening?

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime LiftOff { get; set; }
}

//**************************************
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}

//**********************************
public class EntityManager
{
    public MyEntity AddEntity(MyEntity entity)
    {
        // Method A: Throws exception:
        MyEntity e = null;
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            e = context.MyEntities.Add(entity);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Method B: Works fine:
        e = new MyEntity();
        e.Name = entity.Name;
        e.LiftOff = entity.LiftOff;
        using (MyContext context = new MyContext())
        {
            e = context.MyEntities.Add(e);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return e;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help/advice  you can provide.

**EDIT**: Whether or not EntityManager.AddEntity() Method A works seems to depend on where it's called from: The automated test that adds a patient (using NUnit) runs fine, but when the method is called from a WinForms application assembly, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does your db look like exactly for that table? And you might want to make a small test for that - with the actual data that is failing and try to repeat. You could also check if it's attached but that error doesn't make sense in that case.

Comment: So it's not the `Name` or `LiftOff` columns that are too long - it must be another column - perhaps in a navigation property object?

Comment: @NSGaga Thanks for responding. In method b, which works, I'm able to insert the _exact_ same data that fails for Method A. I would rather not have to manually copy each property from the MyEntity object passed in to a new one (as I do in Method B), though. In my edit, I also state that this code works perfectly fine for my automated tests, which actually hit a database. It's weird, though, that when I call this method from my Winforms exe assembly, it fails.

Comment: i'm saying you should get to the bottom of this - it's 'hiding' some bug very likely (an understatement:). Are you sure that what's failing is actually 'segment A'? It might be something else. And that error doesn't make any sense. You have something 'lurking' in there.

Comment: @NSGaga: I agree with everything you're saying. As I mentioned in my comment to Nick Cardoso's answer, I have a hunch this exception is actually masking the real issue but am not sure at this point how to get to the bottom of this. SaveChanges() call definitely seems to be where things are falling apart, because I've stepped through the code. Why would calling this method from one assembly work but fail when called from another? Why would creating a new object in the AddEntity() method and assigning its properties to the values of the object passed in work? I'd love to hear any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Actually do just that - make a new and assign - and see if you get any more errors - that'd clarify things. And do some tracing/logging - if you can't step through the 'failing code' (when it actually fails). Why couldn't you debug this properly, and see what actually happens? Put try-catch just around that dbcontext Add, if it fails you'll catch it there. Just be meticulous and get rid of things one by one.